# Trying to format a dataframe from a poorly structured excel file

Tags: python, dataframe

Relatively new to python and I have an excel file which is structured like this:

[image: data]

"Compound A" in column A corresponds to the 5 entries below it, "Compound B" in column A corresponds to the 3 entries below it and so on.

I have read it into a pandas data frame to perform some other operations but would like to add a column to the df so that it displays more like this:

[image: expected result]

This could be easily done if the number of entries under each heading was consistent but the problem is that the number of entries under the individual "Compound A/B/C" headings can vary. So I'm not sure how to delineate between them or to indicate when a new Compound heading has started.

Is there a pythonic way of writing:

for all rows beneath "Compound A" add "Compound A" to new "Compound" column and continue until you reach "Column B" and so on...?

Tried a for loop but doesn't always work with different spreadsheets.

Comment: If possible, I suggest you reorganize the Excel files so that they are structured like in your proposal (2nd image). The idea is that the data is organized as if it were in a database table, even if it is in an Excel table.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.